# How to load json file?

Tags: json, reactjs

I am just trying to load JSON file into my react project. I did it like this:

```
fetch(dane).then(response => {
 console.log(response);
 return response.json();
}).then(dane => {
 console.log(dane);
}).catch(err => {
 console.log("Error Reading data " + err);
});
```

and I imported this file into project: 
`import data from "./data.json";`
but I am getting error like this:`Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`
How can I fix it? 
If I am asking about something very stupid, just sorry. 
The json file is in src folder.

Comment: post sample data

Answer (score 0):

You would only use fetch to get the data from an API and assign the response to a variable that you can call.

Since you are using a mock json response stored in a file, you can do the following.

Example:

A file called data.json containing the following.

```
   {
      "name": "John",
      "age": "47",
      "role": "admin"
   }
```

Can be imported via:

`import data from "./data.json"`

Then used in your component however you wish.

```
<h1>Hello {data.name}.</h1>
<h2>Logged in as: {data.role}</h2>
```

Or if used outside of the render, like in a           function:

```
console.log(data.role)
```

Also, `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` seems like your JSON is improperly formatted.

The JSON file should only contain valid JSON data, as shown in my basic example above.